# DeviceOrientation Compass Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, compass, device-orientation

I try to implement a compass using the `deviceorientation` event. I want to use the rotation to rotate an arrow facing in the viewing direction. I'm simply rotating the Image when the `deviceorientation` changes.

On iOS this works like charm by doing the following:

```
if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission === "function") {
          //@ts-ignore
          DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
            .then(permissionState => {
              if (permissionState === "granted") {
                this.compassActive = true;
                window.addEventListener(
                  "deviceorientation",
                  eventData =>
                    this.zone.run(() => {
                      if(!this.compassActive){
                        return false;
                      }
                      //@ts-ignore
                      this.rotatePlayerIcon(eventData.webkitCompassHeading);

                    }),
                  false
                );
              }
            })
            .catch(console.error);
```

Since the `DeviceOrientationEvent.webkitCompassHeading` gives me a clockwise world based presentation of the rotation of the device.

I try the same on Android but I can't find a world based solution. `webkitCompassHeading` does not exist on android so I tried using just `eventData.alpha`. But this gives 0 based on the rotation it was when the event was fired, not based on world north.

All the Guides I find seem outdated.

How do I get a clockwise compass on android like I get on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that alpha is not absolute, means 0 is not north instead 0 is where the device is pointing on activation.

The best way to fix for chrome-based browsers, like most standard Android Browsers ist using an AbsoluteOrientationSensor from W3C Generic Sensor API polyfills.
[Github](https://github.com/kenchris/sensor-polyfills)

The Project I used it in is Typescript based. So here is a Typescript example:

```
import {AbsoluteOrientationSensor} from 'motion-sensors-polyfill'

const options = { frequency: 60, referenceFrame: 'device' };
        const sensor = new AbsoluteOrientationSensor(options);
        sensor.addEventListener('reading', e => {
          this.zone.run(() => {
            var q = e.target.quaternion;
            let alpha = Math.atan2(2*q[0]*q[1] + 2*q[2]*q[3], 1 - 2*q[1]*q[1] - 2*q[2]*q[2])*(180/Math.PI);
            if(alpha < 0) alpha = 360+ alpha;
            this.alpha = 360 - alpha;
            this.rotatePlayerIcon(360 - alpha)
          })
        });
        sensor.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula to calculate compass heading from absolute alpha, beta and gamma is as follows:

```
compass = -(alpha + beta * gamma / 90);
compass -= Math.floor(compass / 360) * 360; // Wrap to range [0,360]
```

The above formula is well-behaved for zero beta and gamma (e.g. phone lying on table), and also works for beta=90 (e.g. held upright).

---

It's 2023 and iOS still doesn't support absolute DeviceOrientationEvent, and Android still doesn't support compass directly.  The following TypeScript code shows how to get the compass value for both types of device.  You can convert it to JavaScript by removing the type specifiers after the colons.

```
function startCompassListener(callback: (compass: number) => void) {
    if (!window["DeviceOrientationEvent"]) {
        console.warn("DeviceOrientation API not available");
        return;
    }
    let absoluteListener = (e: DeviceOrientationEvent) => {
        if (!e.absolute || e.alpha == null || e.beta == null || e.gamma == null)
            return;
        let compass = -(e.alpha + e.beta * e.gamma / 90);
        compass -= Math.floor(compass / 360) * 360; // Wrap into range [0,360].
        window.removeEventListener("deviceorientation", webkitListener);
        callback(compass);
    };
    let webkitListener = (e) => {
        let compass = e.webkitCompassHeading;
        if (compass!=null && !isNaN(compass)) {
            callback(compass);
            window.removeEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", absoluteListener);
        }
    }

    function addListeners() {
        // Add both listeners, and if either succeeds then remove the other one.
        window.addEventListener("deviceorientationabsolute", absoluteListener);
        window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", webkitListener);
    }

    if (typeof (DeviceOrientationEvent["requestPermission"]) === "function") {
        DeviceOrientationEvent["requestPermission"]()
            .then(response => {
                if (response == "granted") {
                    addListeners();
                } else
                    console.warn("Permission for DeviceMotionEvent not granted");
            });
    } else
        addListeners();
}
```

When testing I found that my Android's absolute (alpha,beta,gamma) was very inaccurate (~60 degrees error in alpha).  However, by rolling the device around it calibrated itself and got to ~5 degrees error.

Answer (score 0):

bellow youll seea compass of vtm-mapsforge. it also includes an arrow. appart from the usual magnetometer-accelerometer sensors I recommend using location bearing as the sensors are not at all accurate and get easily disrupted.the nice thing about the compass is that it includes code to make it rotate smoothly as the raw output from the sensors is often noisy.

For the Java code look at [this](https://github.com/mapsforge/vtm/blob/master/vtm-app/src/org/oscim/app/location/Compass.java), it is the original version of the vtm-mapsforge compass

Comment: The solution you provided is written in Java, not Javascript. How should that help me? It's not using the window.ondeviceorientation browser event.

Comment: sorry I just saw the javascript tag. I just blindly assumed it was regarding java. Ill stop editing my code then.